# PHP array merge two arrays on same key What should I do

Tags: php, arrays

**Input: `$a` as `input array` and `$b` as formatting array**

```
$a = Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 5
    [2] => 7
)

$b = Array
(
    [0] => 5
    [1] => 3
    [2] => 4
)


$result = Array
(
    [0] => 1,5
    [1] => 5,3
    [2] => 7,4
)
```

How do I merge 2 arrays to achive the result above with PHP?

Comment: I don't get what `$b` array is used for in this example. You can achieve `$result` without any impact from `$b`. Please explain further, give more detail and use more unique numbers rather than `1, 2,  3`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [array_map](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) function as:

```
<?php

$a = [1, 5, 7];

$b = [5, 3, 4];

$result = array_map(null, $a, $b); // passing null as the callback to perform a zip operation on multiple arrays

print_r($result);

?>
```

**Alternative solution, :P**

```
<?php

$a = [1, 5, 7];

$b = [5, 3, 4];

$result = [];

foreach($a as $k => $v) {
    $result[$k] = [$v, $b[$k]];
}

print_r($result);

?>
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 5
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 5
            [1] => 3
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 7
            [1] => 4
        )

)
```